# how to flash my Nexus 4 and install Ubuntu 13?

Tags: installation, 13.04

I am using Nexus 4.

This is my first time that I am installing a custom ROM / OS. I dont know how to get root access and flash new OS.

Can someone give me the steps?

Answer (score 1):

This must be the page you're looking for :
[Installation instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)